# Create possible combinations in sql alchemy

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

table 1

[image]

table 2

[image]

I have these tables. I wan' to do the following steps.

For all rows with type g in table 1->

1. obtain from table 2 - 1 [a,b] , 2[c,d] , 3 [e,f]
2. create possible combinations and store in table 1 ->

[image]

I'm finding it hard to start on this.
Is there something in sql I can explore?

edge cases ->

- if (1,1,2) is there , then (a,a,c) can't be there
- also a,b,c is same as b,a,c (only one can be there
- type can be g/m/anything

Comment: Can you please explain all edge cases? For example: can there be more than one type in table 1 (or it is always 1 row with type g)?

Answer (score 0):

Join `table1` to 3 copies of `table2`:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (cat1, cat2, cat3, type)
SELECT t21.val, t22.val, t23.val, 'm'
FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t21 ON t21.cat = t1.cat1
INNER JOIN table2 t22 ON t22.cat = t1.cat2
INNER JOIN table2 t23 ON t23.cat = t1.cat3
WHERE t1.type = 'g';
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/y7-ZbNeG).

Comment: I need to add one more condition. if (1,1,2) are there then (a,b,c) can be there but not (b,a,c) or vice-versa (because both are same) , @forpas

Comment: @devb my answer is about the question as you posted it. If you have a new requirement you can ask a new question.